# R language - Creating a function and array out of it

Tags: r, arrays, function, if-statement, integer

I need to create a function in R called "Zufall(n,max)" which returns "n" random integers between "1" and "max"(max is an argument to the function and not a the function max()!!). Integers can appear repeatedly.

```
Zufall <- function(n,mx){
Zahl <- 1:mx  
if(!is.double(n)) stop("Geben sie eine ganzzahlige Zahl ein!")
  if(Zahl>mx) stop("Geben sie eine ganzzahlige Zahl ein!")
  else sample(n,replace=T)
}
```

1. My problem ist that the "mx" is ignored by the code - i generate values higher than the mx-value! E.g. when I enter "Zufall(1000,8)", I generate the integer "719" ... that should not be the case; numbers shall stop at "8" in this case!
2. How do I best create an array of dimension 2x3x4 out of it?

Thank you very much ..appreciating your helb!

Comment: Is that R? Please tag appropriately so people who know your language can help.

Comment: Yes, it is R - I edited my answer now :). Thank you!

Comment: Please indent your function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply:

```
sample(1:mx, n, replace = TRUE)
```

for instance `sample(1:8, 1000, replace = TRUE)`.

Your condition `if(Zahl>mx)` is wrong since Zahl is a vector of length > 1, anyway this test is useless since by construction `1:mx` will not generate any number > mx